# Слияние в GIT и командная работа

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с командной работой в Git.
Пока работа настроена так:
2 программиста: 1 делает работу, другой проверяет.

Тот который делает получает таски, для выполнения каждого таска создает новую ветку после после того как выполнил задание пушит эту ветку на сервер, сливает ветку со своим мастером делает новую ветку для таска и т.д.

Проверяющий забирает ветки с сервера и делает проверку если все ок вливает их в мастер отправляет на сервер. Если сделаны ошибки возобновляет таск.

Это все как-то коряво, я думаю можно сделать лучше, подскажите как, наведите на правильный путь!

Сейчас проблемы возникают на этапе проверки при слиянии веток. Как можно слить только те комиты которые были сделаны в сливаемой ветке ?

Comment: Напишите подробней про окружение, в котором вы ведете разработку: какое ПО для работы с GIT у вас стоит на сервере? Почему вы не используете Pull Request?

Comment: Ни какого особенного ПО не стоит, только Git.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Как можно слить только те комиты которые были сделаны в сливаемой ветке ?

В git под термином «ветка» (branch) подразумевается *указатель* на коммит, а не набор коммитов, как в некоторых других системах управления версиями файлов.

Иными словами, это *точка*, а не *отрезок*.

Вам требуется перенести несколько коммитов (*отрезок*), а для этого нужно указать две *точки*.

К примеру: одобренная задача решалась в ветке task125, а предыдущая, пока не одобренная задача, решалась в ветке task124.

Тогда для включения (в текущую ветку) одобренных коммитов (*отрезка* между этими двумя *точками*) можно использовать такую, например, команду:

```
git cherry-pick task124..task125
```

Comment: а в плане организации, вероятно, более удобным (для обоих программистов) будет такой алгоритм: разработчику лучше создавать новые ветки для решения задач, основываясь не на «сборной солянке», в которой внесены и одобренные и неодобренные коммиты, а на той ветке, где находятся только одобренные коммиты. тогда проверяющему достаточно сделать просто `git merge taskNNN`, не задумываясь о том где начинается *отрезок*.

Comment: Пришел вот к такому виду


 1. Клонируется репозиторий с сервера для разработки 
 2. Для каждой задачи создается своя ветка разработки
 3. После того как задача выполнена делается Push ветки на сервер разработки 
 4. Возвращаемся на основную ветку делаем pull с сервера разработки
 5. Создаем новую ветку для новой задачи 

Если задача решена с ошибками то переходим на ветку с таском вливаем в нее ветку мастер (что бы актуализировать изменения) и вносим все необходимые правки и отправляешь на сервер разработки

Comment: @zsiteru да, вполне логичный алгоритм.